# CSS variables and at-rules

Tags: css

I have run into a problem involving CSS variables and at-rules. I have the following variables declared in the `:root` scope:

```
:root {
    --font-weight-light:    300;
    --font-weight-normal:   400;
    --font-weight-semibold: 600;
}
```

and the following at-rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:  'Proxima Nova';
    font-display: swap;
    font-style:   normal;
    font-weight:  var(--font-weight-light);
    src: url('/fonts/proximanova-light.woff') format('woff');
}

/* other font-face rules for other font variants */
```

When I try to use these declarations to style my paragraph:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-light);
}
```

the result is not as expected (light font variant), instead the font variant is the last declared.

When I hardcode `font-weight: 300;` in the at-rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:  'Proxima Nova';
    font-display: swap;
    font-style:   normal;
    font-weight:  300; /* var(--font-weight-light) */
    src: url('/fonts/proximanova-light.woff') format('woff');
}
```

everything seems to work.

I suspect that my case does not work because `:root` is a base class for all selectors, while at-rules do not belong under `:root`. That way at-rules cannot access CSS variables defined in `:root`.

How could I fix this problem? Or am I missing something?

Thank you!

P.S. I would like to solve this problem using standard CSS. I know about SASS variables, etc. Thank you! :)

**Update**

I put together a runable code snippet which illustrates the problem. The font of paragraph should be Arial, but instead we see Comic Sans...

```css
:root {
  --font-weight-light:    300;
  --font-weight-semibold: 600;
}

@font-face {
  font-family:  'Foo Sans';
  font-display: swap;
  font-style:   normal;
  font-weight:  var(--font-weight-light);
  src:          local('Arial');
}

@font-face {
  font-family:  'Foo Sans';
  font-display: swap;
  font-style:   normal;
  font-weight:  var(--font-weight-semibold);
  src:          local('Comic Sans MS');
}

p {
  font-family: 'Foo Sans';
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-light);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Text</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras interdum ullamcorper elementum. In vitae mi viverra, congue nisi in, accumsan libero. Cras convallis, tortor ac semper molestie, ex orci dapibus dolor, at suscipit enim magna vel ligula. Suspendisse quis tristique urna. Quisque posuere mi sed sem faucibus malesuada. Duis quis orci bibendum sapien rhoncus sollicitudin. Donec sodales magna ut blandit porttitor. Proin dictum augue a justo vehicula auctor.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `the result is not as expected (light font variant), instead the font variant is the last declared.` --> can you explain this ? what is the output you have ?

Comment: Hello Temani, yes sure. I have three `@font-face` declarations for light, normal and semibold font variants. Semibold is the last font variant and my paragraph uses semibold instead of light.

Comment: the issue with with cascading .. the CSS variable are custom properties so they cascade like normal property for parent to child ... in your case when using @font-face you cannot see these varialbe [am not sure at 100% but i guess it's this, am looking to the documenation ]

Comment: Thank you Temani! I have also put together a code snippet, which illustrates the problem. Maybe it will give more hints.

Comment: ah but your issue is clear, you are using the same name, so you are overriding the first one ... you sould use different name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom CSS properties in @font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752373/custom-css-properties-in-font-face)

Answer (score -3):

Actually `browsers` not render `CSS` `variable` `value`. Instead of it `render` `var(--font-weight-light);`. But your `CSS` `variable` property will work. Because `browser` isn't a compiler. See the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/j2vr56). Also this `rules` isn't support `IE`, `Opera` and all of older version `browsers`. [Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

```css
:root {
  --font-weight-light:   300;
  --font-weight-regular: 400;
  --font-weight-bold:    700;
}
div{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-bold);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```