# Custom CSS properties in @font-face

Tags: css

The body should display a handwriting font but will only do so if the comment line is uncommented.

It seems I cannot use custom properties in @font-face? Tested on FF and Chrome.

What's going on here?

```css
:root {
  --backgroundColor: cornflowerblue;
  --textColor: white;
  --fontName: 'Indie Flower';
}

@font-face {
  font-family: var(--fontName); 
  /* font-family: 'Indie Flower'; */
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
  color: var(--textColor);
  font-family: var(--fontName);
}
```

```html
<p>Custom CSS properties don't work inside @font-face rule?</p>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is how the `font-name` is actually output for the browser to read. Remove the quote marks for the root var, and add them around the call to the variable.

```css
:root {
  --backgroundColor: cornflowerblue;
  --textColor: white;
  --fontName: Indie Flower;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'var(--fontName)';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
  color: var(--textColor);
  font-family: 'var(--fontName)';
}
```

```html
<p>Custom CSS properties don't work inside @font-face rule?</p>
```

**Edit**
Here's the version with a fallback.

```css
:root {
  --backgroundColor: cornflowerblue;
  --textColor: white;
  --fontName: "Indie Flower";
  --fallBack: sans-serif;
  --fullFont: 'var(--fontName)', var(--fallBack);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'var(--fontName)';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
  color: var(--textColor);
  font-family: 'var(--fontName)', var(--fallBack);
}

p {
   font-family: var(--fullFont);
}
```

```html
<p>Custom CSS properties don't work inside @font-face rule?</p>
```

Comment: That solves the problem, but is it really how it's supposed to work? How would that work with fallback fonts, like `font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;`?

Comment: For the fallback font, in your use case, you would not add that to the `--fontName` var, as that would mess up your @font-face. You would simply add another variable as the fallback, or just put sans-serif after the var `font-family: 'var(--fontName)', sans-serif;`

Comment: For how it's supposed to work, yeah. So, if you look at what you were trying to pass with the quotes (without the quotes around the `var(--fontName)` - you were getting `"Indie Flower"` - I'm assuming because it was passed as a string, the `font-family` was reading it literally is `"Indie Flower"` - not as `"` around "Indie Flower" if that makes sense. Here's the W3.org documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#custom-property offers a little more insight.

Comment: In my original code example `font-family: var(--fontName);` works on the body selector, but not on @font-face. That seems inconsistent.

Comment: Maybe because the `@` rule is processed differently than a selector. In your original example, if you wrap the `font-family: 'var(--fontName)';` in your `@font-face`, it would work. Again, that could be because of how the variable is passed with the quotes as part of the string vs. a wrapping element. I'm not sure. That's something perhaps the spec developers could answer.

Comment: What? How does it event work? You just pass a string instead of a variable value...

Comment: @StyleSh1t not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: The answer you gave here doesn't really utilize CSS custom properties. You just set a string as a `font-family`.

Comment: @StyleSh1t  What? What do you think a CSS custom property is? Did you read any of the comments along with the answer to why this was set? This perfectly answered the OPs question and was also answered a year and a half ago. If you think you have a better solution, write an answer. If you change `--fontName` in the `:root`, it will update the `font-family`. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: @disinfor I think the issue here is that instead of using the value of the custom property, you're using the custom property name. So given a custom property: `--font: MyCoolFont` setting `font-family: 'var(--font)'` is setting the font-family to literally be "var(--font)" instead of "MyCoolFont".

Comment: @fatslug - OK. This still solves the original issue. Do you have a better solution? Post it as an answer - especially if you're going to down vote.

Answer (score 15):

Your original suspicion that CSS properties don't work inside `@font-face` is accurate. The accepted answer is incorrect and only appears to work because of a mistake (see below).

I checked in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, and none of them accept a `@font-face` in which a descriptor includes a `var()` function. Firefox developer edition was particularly helpful, since it let me see that the @font-face rule isn't being parsed *at all* with `font-family: var(--fontName);`

I also tried using a custom property for the `src` descriptor, which also failed.

As far as I can tell, the [CSS @font-face specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#font-face-rule) says nothing about whether custom properties should work or not. **No browser has chosen to make them work.** This makes considerable sense, as a single font family's source file and properties are not likely to be *variable*.

If you have to dynamically construct @font-face rules client-side, the best method is using the [FontFace API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace) in a script. If absolutely necessary you could even read from your CSS properties with `getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue("--fontName")`.

---

The accepted answer only seems to work because it redefines the font family name in @font-face, setting it to a string with the *literal value* of 'var(--fontName)'. It also sets the body `font-family: 'var(--fontName)'`. The two strings match, so the font loads.

**CSS functions like `var()` are NEVER evaluated inside of a string.** Everything between the opening and closing quotes is evaluated literally, as [this diagram](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#typedef-string-token) from the CSS syntax spec shows. So @disinfor's code isn't referencing the `--fontName: "Indie Flower";` set on `:root` at all.

As a demonstration, see what happens when we *unquote* the `font-family` on body, so it actually evaluates the `var()`. The "Indie Flower" font doesn't exist in the document, so it doesn't load, but a font named "var(--fontName)" *does* exist, and will load:

```css
:root {
  --backgroundColor: cornflowerblue;
  --textColor: white;
  --fontName: "Indie Flower";
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'var(--fontName)';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
  color: var(--textColor);
  font-family: var(--fontName);
}
.use-the-string {
  font-family: 'var(--fontName)';
}
```

```html
<p>This tries to use "Indie Flower", but it doesn't exist.</p>
<p class="use-the-string">This uses the font named "var(--fontName)"</p>
```

Comment: Glad you found the real cause. I didn't hunt it down as far as you did! Upvote.

Comment: @disinfor Cheers and thanks :) It's a weird little edge-case to be sure! It would be nice if the spec took a clear position on it one way or another. There are other blocks like `@keyframes` that technically have identical semantics, and custom props work fine there, so it's natural to assume they ought to work in `@font-face` as well.

Comment: @Andron My use case was that I wanted to use the same CSS for different websites and only have to exchange the font-family name (and src) in :root. I eventually achieved this by defining seperate font-face rules for each font and using a font-family var on the affected HTML elements.